# Error in int array

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I wanted to write a program that takes an N integer and an array of N integers as input. I'm having errors with my code atm.

```
    //use the following code to fetch input from console 
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Use the following code to print output
    int length = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int[] arr = new int[length];
    for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++)
    {
       arr[counter] = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: Post the errors that you get

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` requires a string parameter. You're passing it an `int`.

Comment: please share the full code. as per this you are not passing String to Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 2):

Do :  `arr[counter] = reader.nextInt();`
Instead of:  `arr[counter] = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextInt());`

Answer (score 1):

**Modifications:**

1. Change `arr[counter] = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextInt());` to `arr[counter] = reader.nextInt();`.

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

         //Use the following code to print output
         int length = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
         int[] arr = new int[length];

         for (int counter = 0; counter < length; counter++){
             arr[counter] = reader.nextInt();
         }

         for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
         System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

**Integer.parseInt():** - This method is used to get the primitive data type of a certain String.

**Syntax:** - `static int parseInt(String s)`

You were trying to read an `int` value instead of a `String`.